# Why does Visual Studio not know the correct definition of this struct?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, struct

I've got a weird issue that almost seems like a Visual Studio 2008 issue.  I have a C struct definition as follows:

```
static struct frame {
    short typupdt;
    char callarg[1+CallSiz];
    char *unitarg;
    XTime unitage;
    XTime orgtime;
    XTime newtime;
    char oldstat[1+StatSiz];
    char newstat[1+StatSiz];
    char incdisp[1+DispSiz];
    char orgdisp[1+DispSiz];
    char clearcod[1+ClearSiz];
    char orgclear[1+ClearSiz];
    char observd[1+ObsSiz];
    char orgobs[1+ObsSiz];
    char raddesc[1+Desc1Siz];
    char incnum[INVIDLEN];
    char agency[1+AgencySiz];
    int wlins;
    int wcols;
    int skipsrch;
    struct frame *next;
} *Frame= NULL;
```

Which should (and seems to) create a new `struct` called `frame` and a global pointer (to this file) to an instance of that `struct` called `Frame`.  That all seems to work fine in the code itself.  However, when I am debugging this code and set a break point somewhere and then examine `Frame` in the watch window, the information it reports is completely wrong.  It's like it's looking at the correct piece of memory, but its understanding of the definition is incorrect, i.e. the fields it says the struct has are not even close.

At first I thought there was sort of weird namespacing issue or something so I changed the names of both `frame` and `Frame`, but the issue still existed.  Anybody have any idea what is going on?  Like I said, the code seems to work, but debugging is pretty much impossible.

Edit: I updated the definition with the *real* definition, and here's a screenshot of what I see in the watch window:

[alt text http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/6943/watchlist.jpg](http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/6943/watchlist.jpg)

That Make a lick of sense to anybody? I'm still super stumped.

Comment: Well, since none of the answer seem to have helped, it's probably time for you to provide a small, compilable example that shows the error you run into, so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Definitely post a small example that shows the problem - I tried this with a `struct frame` that I added a few fields to and had no problems in the debugger displaying the contents of what `Frame` points to.

Comment: Added the original definition and what I see in the watch window when I'm broken in the file somewhere.

Comment: I can find the struct the watch window is displaying and it seems to be declared the same way, `static struct frame { ... } *Frame = NULL;`, but I *swear* even after changing the name of the struct and the instance of the struct, I had this same problem... plus, it's in a different file, also declared static.

Comment: When the breakpoint 'activates' is the `struct frame` in scope? Do you have more variables named `Frame`, possibly static to another translation unit or local to some function ... ?

Comment: `Frame` is definitely in scope, as it's in direct use in the code at this point (and the code works).  Like I mentioned, there are other `Frame` variables, but none that I can see as also being in scope here, mostly due to the `static` declarations.

Comment: Okay, apparently I had only tried renaming the `frame` or the `Frame` rather than both at the same time.  When I renamed both, it seemed to work.  I'm still a little curious as to what *really* was going on here, as the code itself compiled and ran just fine.  VS bug?

Comment: "WORKAROUND: Microsoft strongly recommends that you use unique type definitions." See here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822551

Comment: @pmg - That's the problem exactly. Throw that in an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.  Thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something about your situation described by Microsoft: [FIX: Wrong Type Definition Appears in Visual Studio .NET Debugger](http://web.archive.org/web/20130709005922/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822551)

> **WORKAROUND**: Microsoft strongly recommends that you use unique type definitions. By using unique type definitions, you can avoid any confusion about the true value of a data structure. However, if you cannot use unique type definitions, you can also avoid the problem by using namespaces, as in the following sample code:
>
> ```
> namespace MyNamespace {
> struct IDENTICALSTRUCT {
> ...;
> };
>
> using namespace MyNamespace;
> ```
>
> The debugger can then resolve the type definitions correctly.

Comment: As detailed in the above comments, this appears to be the issue.  Definitely spectacularly annoying.

Comment: Strange - the KB indicates that the problem is in VS 2003 and they have a hotfix for it.  Looks like the fix regressed in VS 2005 or VS 2008.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this

```
struct foo { /*...*/ } * bar;
```

defines `bar` to be a `foo*`, not a `foo`. Try

```
struct foo { /*...*/ } bar;
```

instead.

Comment: The rest of the code in the file assume that `Frame` is a pointer to a `frame` rather than an instance of it itself. If I do what you suggest, it would no longer be. Also unsure why that would be an issue?

Comment: It's not an issue if you know what you're doing. For example, `sizeof(*bar)` will give you the size of the struct, but `sizeof(bar)` only gives you the size of the pointer. On 32bit machines with 8bit `char` pointers are 4 bytes, hence `sizeof(bar)==4`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a Debug build? Debugging a release build will often seem to work, but the debugger will report garbage values for variables.

If that's not it, then I'd try to verify if it is a compiler/syntax issue by splitting up the definition so you define the struct as a typedef and then define the pointer in a separate statement. (This would arguably make the code more readable/maintainable anyway - if you don't trust the code above then rewriting it in a way that you do trust is advisable)

Comment: I am definitely in Debug (I've never even compiled a Release build of our app... whole other team does those sorts of things).  Also: good advice about splitting the statement.  I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the `struct frame` and defining a variable of that type in different statements.

```
struct frame {
    /* .. Various other fields, etc */
    struct frame *next;
};
static struct frame *Frame = NULL;
```

Maybe the `static` messes up Visual Studio.

Comment: Great idea (what Jason suggested also), but just tried it and it still didn't work.  Completely baffled here.