# Visual Studio 2008 Intellisense with struct keyword

Tags: c, visual-studio, intellisense

I am using visual studio 2008 express edition.

A normal win32 console C project with the code below:

```
int main(void)
{

struct _addr_info
{
    char name[30];
    char street[40];
    char city[20];
    char state[3];
    unsigned long int zip;
} addr_info;

addr_info.zip = 12345;


return 0;
}
```

Generally for structures intellisense will list the members. Here it doesnt however it compiles fine and at debugging i checked the data also gets entered properly. Am i doing something wrong.

even this code has same prob.

```
int main(void)
{

struct 
{
    char name[30];
    char street[40];
    char city[20];
    char state[3];
    unsigned long int zip;
} addr_info;

addr_info.zip = 12345;


return 0;
}
```

This code below also doesn't work.

```
int main(void)
{

struct _addr_info
{
    char name[30];
    char street[40];
    char city[20];
    char state[3];
    unsigned long int zip;
} ;

struct _addr_info addr_info;
addr_info.zip = 12345;


return 0;
}
```

The code below works fine and list the members of the structure.

```
struct _addr_info
{
    char name[30];
    char street[40];
    char city[20];
    char state[3];
    unsigned long int zip;
} addr_info;

int main(void)
{
    addr_info.zip = 12345;
    return 0;
}
```

This one too.

```
    struct _addr_info
{
    char name[30];
    char street[40];
    char city[20];
    char state[3];
    unsigned long int zip;
} ;

int main(void)
{
    struct _addr_info addr_info;
    addr_info.zip = 12345;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: duplicate? [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574875/ ]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Visual Studio not know the correct definition of this struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574875/why-does-visual-studio-not-know-the-correct-definition-of-this-struct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted on MSDN forum and got the answer pointed by the link.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/8a22dc4a-3632-4cb9-92a3-63a18b55e7b6

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're used to Visual C#'s intellisense then you'll be extremely disappointed in Visual C++'s as it's very buggy. You can try deleting the ncb files but you're better off using something like Visual Assist which is an intellisense replacement.

Comment: deleting ncb and rebuilding solution (after cleaning) doesnt make any difference.

Comment: Visual Assist is paid and seems doesnt support any express edition.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer copied from [ [Why does Visual Studio not know the correct definition of this struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574875/) ]*

There's something about your situation described by Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822551

> **WORKAROUND**: Microsoft strongly recommends that you use unique type
>   definitions.